# How can web pages be coded so that search engines assign a higher page rank to the latest version?

Tags: html, seo

I frequently use Google to search for .NET documentation, and invariably, the highest ranked pages are for old versions of the .NET framework.

For example, I just did a Google search for "c# extern".

- The first result was for Visual Studio 2005.
- The second result was for Visual Studio .NET 2003.
- I went through several pages and never did come across the [Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page.

Interestingly, I tried the same search on Bing, Microsoft's own search engine, and Visual Studio 2005 was still the first hit. However, the second hit was the one I was looking for (Visual Studio 2010).

I realize that many documentation pages on MSDN have a menu at the top that allows you to switch versions, but I don't think it should be necessary to do this. There should be an HTML way to convince search engines that two pages are very similar, and one is newer/more relevant than the other.

Is there anything that can be done in HTML to force a documentation page for a more recent version to get a higher page rank than an essentially equivalent page for an older version?

Answer (score 2):

**You can't tell Google what page is preferred**
*(That's basically the answer to your question)*

If someone googles `c# extern`, that person will get the most relevant pages calculated by googles algorithms. It will differ from user to user and where you are located, but far most how links all over the internet are directed. You can not change this with on-page optimization.

Canonical addresses mentioned by [Wander Nauta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658048/570796) is not suppose to be used in this manner. We use canonical addresses basically if we wish to tell Google or any other bot that two or more pages are the same. This is not what you where asking for. It would remove the older versions from indexing entirely in favor of the page addressed as the canonical address.

> Quoted from http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394
>
> *Of all these pages with **identical content**, this page is the most useful. Please prioritize it in search results.*
>
> ...
>
> *The rel="canonical" attribute should be used only to specify the preferred version of many pages with **identical content**...*

---

To lead the client correct I would use, as you already described, a good web interface on the page so that the client easily can find what he or she is looking for.

---

Google also offers sitelinks for your search results that may or may not appear. I would say this is where you come closest to be able to direct your clients to the most relevant page by your standards on the search page.

> Quoted from https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334
>
> *...sitelinks, are meant to help users navigate your site. Our systems analyze the link structure of your site to find shortcuts that will save users time and allow them to quickly find the information they're looking for.*

In Googles Webmaster Tools you have an option where you can optimize thees links, at least somewhat.

> Quoted from [Googles Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CGUQFjAA&url=http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/&ei=5Bm4T_ewOc704QTtjf3HCQ&usg=AFQjCNHzw4v7cHMZ9WeuuM4BZp6bSIyNlw&sig2=kIOfDiUiAcF8K8dEG7Isig)
>
> *Sitelinks are automatically generated links that may appear under your site's search results. ...
>
>   If you don't want a page to appear as a sitelink, you can demote it.*

---

### Update

You could theoretically specify what version something on your page is in with "microdata" or similar. By doing this you have at least told the bots that there are two items on this site with the same name but in different versions. I don't think this will have any effect in witch order your sites will be listed in the search result thought. *But we never know what the future holds right?*

If you check out [schema.org](http://schema.org/) you'll see [CreativeWork](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) has an property named "version" and [SoftwareApplication](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) has one named "softwareVersion".

Google uses microdata to create [rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170). I haven't heard that Google uses it for anything else but that does of course not mean it isn't so.

Answer (score 1):

Google allows you to specify a *canonical address* for a specific resource, i.e. the version of a given page you want Google to prioritize. [It's pretty easy to use.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)

However, hints like these are always suggestions. That is, the search engine is free to ignore them, if they support them at all.

Comment: Good answer, +1, but this only really allows you to say "this page is the latest", it doesn't allow you to say "this page is the second latest" or "this page is the oldest".

Comment: My guess would be that search engines, by default, probably knows which page is the second oldest or whatever, but they just don't care. If everyone links to the 2005 version, that version is the most interesting, no matter how old it is.

Comment: I would agree that Google knows the ages of pages (after all, it lets you restrict searches by age), but it doesn't necessarily know that pages are different versions of the same thing.

Comment: @DanM I updated my answer with how one may specify what version an item has using microdata. I don't think that it will have any impact on the order of the listed pages though. What Wander Nauta is saying about linking should still be prioritized by my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

For that you would need to know the actual algorithms. I'm guessing that most search engines do a comparison on how well the page matches the search but then also take into account the amount of hits a site gets. So say you have a 98% match with 1000 hits and a 96% match with 5000 hits. The second page may still be ranked higher.

As for what you can do, search engines are "blind" so use CSS and avoid tables for layout purposes. This will allow the engine to get a better match with your content. For a workaround with old version, you could redirect traffic coming in to the new version and then have a link to the old version on that page. Essentially setting it up so that only following that link takes you to the old page.

Answer (score 0):

Since at it's core Google's search is based on links (pagerank algorithm), it would certainly help if each page of the old version linked to it's respective page on the new version. This might not solve the problem completely, but it would certainly help.